# Use localStorage to hold ajax response and then use as object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, local-storage

Hi have the following Ajax request that gets JSON from the server and stores the json in localStorage for which I can use in my application. It seems like my code to accomplish this is not efficient at all, but I cant get it to work any other way. I have tried storing as an object, but it seems to want to be stored as a string.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
//GET Users List from Server
function getUsersList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/ListUsers",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e) {

            localStorage.UsersList = (JSON.stringify(e));
            var usersList = localStorage.UsersList;
            var usersList = $.parseJSON(usersList)
            console.log(usersList[0])
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Because [DOM Storage does store them as strings (see second Note).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#Storage) Thus, to store objects, they need to be serializable to store, and deserializable to retrieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only store strings in the `localStorage`, however you could create an abstraction of the serialization/deserialization process in a reusable function.

Have a look at [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Also, it's recommended to use the `setItem` and `getItem` methods.